# SQL Code to order by data from related table

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay this SQL query is giving me a headache, hoping theres someone who's done something like this before.

I have two tables (truncated)

```
tblTickets:               tblNotes:
    ticketno (int)            noteid (int)
    firmid (int)              ticketno (int)
    ticket_desc (text)        datecreated (datetime)
    ...                       ...
```

They are related in that a Ticket can have many Notes

What I need to do is create a query that searches by firmid (i.e. 32) and orders the "Tickets" by their latest "Note" using tblNotes.datecreated (ordered newest first)

Thanks!

NB. MySQL server (5.5.32)

EDIT: To those who've marked the question down: I have tried, and the furthest successful SQL I got was to list all tickets and notes joined by using JOIN on ticketno, I didnt add this code to the question because I guessed I was going about it all the wrong way, and maybe I needed to use a UNION, something I've always found tricky to use.

I need it to only search by the latest note for each ticket. Thats what I needed help on.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: what have you done so far? what are the results?

Comment: @James . . . This is a rather basic query.  Do you have any knowledge of SQL at all?

Comment: I downvoted because this is not your personal coding army. This is a Q&A forum.

Comment: Look into joins that should get you started.

Comment: I have tried, and the furthest successful SQL I got was to list all tickets and notes joined (similar to the answer given by Conrad Lotz below).  But I need it to only search by the latest note for each ticket.  Thats what I need help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query within the `WHERE` clause of your SQL to identify the last note date and then join to the SQ to limit the notes that are returned.

The following should be enought to get you started.

```
SELECT  ...
FROM    tblTickets T
INNER JOIN
        tblNotes N
ON      N.ticketno = T.ticketno
INNER JOIN
        (SELECT N1.ticketno
                ,MAX(N1.datecreated) AS last_note_date
        FROM    tblNotes N1
        GROUP BY
                N1.ticketno
        )SQ
ON      N.ticketno = SQ.ticketno
AND     N.datecreated = SQ.last_note_date
```